# A modified median

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, optimization

Assume we have real numbers $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$.
Consider the following function which returns the average distance of a point $t$ from $x_1,\dots,x_n.$
$$
D_1(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - t|.
$$

It is well known that $D_1(t)$ is minimized at a median of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

I am interested in the centrality parameter that is obtained when the mean is replaced by the median above (you may assume $n$ is odd and $n \geq 3$ if it helps).

So, my question is this : Is there a simple expression for $$ \arg\min D_2(t) $$ where
$$
D_2(t) = \operatorname{median}\{|x_1-t|,\dots,|x_n-t|\}?
$$

I have done some numerical experiments. I think that there is always a minimum at a point of the form $\frac{x_i + x_j}{2}$ where $i \leq j$ and $\frac{x_i+x_j}{2}\leq x_{i+1}.$

This problem is combinatorial because one has to keep track of how the order of $|x_i - t|$'s change as $t$ changes.

Update: User [Joe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/693577/joe) has conjectured that if $n=2k+1$ is odd then the minimum occurs that $t = \frac{x_m + x_{m+k}}{2}$ where $m = \arg\min (x_{m+k} - x_m)$.

The plot of the objective function for $1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 20$ shows that a median may not be the minimizer. The conjecture is valid here (k=3), a minimum occurs at $\frac{x_1+x_4}{2}$ and $x_4-x_1=9$.

[image: An example where median is not the minimizer, conjecture holds (k=3)]

Another example where the conjecture is valid. Here $k=4$ and the minimum occurs at $\frac{x_1+x_5}{2}=3.$

[image]

Comment: It seems to me, although I could be wrong, that, if $n=2k+1$, then $t$ would be the median of the two points $x_{m}$ and $x_{m+k+1}$ such that $m$ is the argmin of $x_{m+k+1} - x_m$

Comment: Notice that for the data used for your plot that $10-1=11-2=12-3$, which is why the three values of $t$ are:$$\frac{10+1}{2},\frac{11+2}{2}, \text{ and } \frac{12+3}{2}$$

Comment: @Joe  : If your conjecture holds then there is an O(n) algorithm for computing this modified median.

Comment: Sorry O(n log n) since the data has to be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given real numbers $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$.

I will consider the case of $n = 2k+1$.

$$
D_2(t) = \operatorname{median}\{|x_1-t|,\dots,|x_n-t|\}
$$

$D_2(t)$ is continuous, and attains its minimum on $[x_1,x_n]$.

Let$$d^* = \min_{t\in \mathbb{R}} D_2(t)$$

Let $t$ be such that $D_2(t) = d^*$. Then we know that there are at least $k+1$ points $x_i$ such that $|x_i-t|\le d^*$.

Therefore, there are at least $k+1$ points $x_i$ in $[t-d^*, t+d^*]$.

Let $A$ be the subset of points in $[t-d^*, t+d^*]$

If  $A \subset (t-d^*, t+d^*]$ , then we could let:$$t_2 = \frac{\min A + (t+d^*)}{2}$$
Which would give $k+1$ points less than a distance $d^*$ from $t_2$, contradicting that $d^*$ was the min.

Similarly for $A \subset [t-d^*, t+d^*)$.

Hence, $\min A = t-d^*$ and $\max A = t+d^*$.

Since $i<j \implies x_i<x_j$, this implies that there are exactly $k+1$ points in $[t-d^*, t+d^*]$, for otherwise we could take a subset of $A$ consisting of only $k+1$ points, by removing the maximum or minimum of $A$, to attain a value for $D_2(t)$ less than $d^*$, by the same argument as above.

Hence, $\min A = x_m = t-d^*$ and $\max A = x_{m+k} = t+d^*$, and $$t=\frac{x_m + x_{m+k}}{2}$$

Therefore, to find a $t$, you should first find $d^*$, which is the minimum of $\displaystyle\frac{x_{m+k} - x_m}{2}$ for $1 \le m \le n-k$, and use any points $x_m$ and $x_{m+k}$ that are $2d^*$ apart.

Comment: A beautiful proof. I am at loss for words.

Comment: That is very kind of you. It was an interesting problem to think about. Thank you for posting it!

Comment: Your proof should work for n=2k also provided we define the median to be the kth largest value, i.e., $X_{(\frac{n}{2})}$.

Comment: Yes, I think so, but it would be interesting to know what it is for the actual definition of median. That seems trickier to me, since the median distance is not one of the distances.

Comment: I have a proof for $n=2k$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof for even $n = 2k$ with $k > 1$.

The median for any $-\infty < a_1 \leq \dots \leq a_{2k} < \infty$ is defined to be mean of the $k^{th}$ and $(k+1)^{th}$ largest elements : $M = \dfrac{a_{k}+a_{k+1}}{2}$.

Assume $n = 2k$ with $k > 1$ and $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_{n}$.

**Result** $$\inf D_2(t) = \min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \frac{x_{i+k}-x_{i}}{2}.$$ $\arg\min D_2(t) = \dfrac{x_{i^*} + x_{i^*+k}}{2}$ where $ i^* = \arg\min_{i} (x_{i+k}-x_i)$.

We will need the following lemma.

**Lemma**
For all $1 \leq i \leq k$
$$
D_2(\frac{x_i+x_{i+k}}{2}) = \frac{x_{i+k}-x_i}{2}
$$
**Proof of lemma**
$t_0 = \dfrac{x_i+x_{i+k}}{2}$ is the midpoint of the interval $[x_i,x_{i+k}]$. Let $d_1 \leq d_2 \dots \leq d_n$ be the elements of $|x_1-t_0|,\dots,|x_n - t_0|$ written in increasing order. Since the $k+1$ closest $x$'s to $t_0$ are $x_i,x_{i+1},\dots,x_{i+k}$ in some order and since $x_i$ and $x_{i+k}$ are the points at largest distances from $t_0$ in $[x_i,x_{i+k}]$ we have $d_k = d_{k+1} = \dfrac{x_{i+k}-x_i}{2}.$

So, $D_2(\dfrac{x_i+x_{i+k}}{2}) = \dfrac{1}{2}(d_k+d_{k+1}) = \dfrac{x_{i+k}-x_i}{2}.$

**Proof of main result**
Let $d_0 = \inf D_2(t)$.

We will show that there is an $i$ such that $D_2(\frac{1}{2}(x_i + x_{i+k})) = \frac{1}{2}(x_{i+k} - x_i) = d_0.$

Let $t_0$ be such that $d_0 = D_2(t_0).$

From the properties of the median, *at least* $k$ of $|x_i - t_0|,\dots,|x_n-t_0|$  must be less than or equal to $d_0$, or equivalently, $I=[t_0-d_0,t_0+d_0]$ must contain at least $k$ of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.
First consider the case when $I$ contains at least $k+1$ of the $x$'s, say, $t_0 - d_0 \leq x_i < \dots < x_{i+k} \leq t_0 + d_0.$

The minimality of $d_0$ means
$$
\begin{align}
D_2(\frac{x_i + x_{i+k}}{2}) - d_0 &\geq 0
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x_{i+k} - (t_0+d_0)}{2}+\frac{(t_0-d_0)-x_i}{2} &\geq 0
\end{align} 
$$
Since $t_0-d_0 \leq x_i < x_{i+k} \leq t_0 + d_0$, that is, $x_{i+k} - (t_0+d_0) \leq 0$ and $(t_0-d_0)-x_i \leq 0$ this implies $x_i = t_0 - d_0$ and $x_{i+k}=t_0+d_0$. So $t_0 = \dfrac{x_i+x_{i+k}}{2}$ and $d_0 = \dfrac{x_{i+k}-x_i}{2} = D_2(\dfrac{x_{i+k}+x_i}{2})$.

Finally consider the case when $I$ contains exactly $k$ $x$'s, say $t_0-d_0 \leq x_i < \dots < x_{i+k-1} \leq t_0+d_0$. Since $x \to |x-t_0|$ is a convex function, the maximum of $|t_0-x_i|,\dots,|t_0-x_{i+k-1}|$ must occur at $x_i$ or $x_{i+k-1}$. By construction $x_i,\dots,x_{i+k-1}$ are the closest $k$ points among $x$'s to $t_0$. The next closest point must be one of $x_{i+k}$ or $x_{i-1}$. Assume the next closest point among $x$'s to $t_0$ is $x_{i+k}$.  The proof when we assume the next closest point is $x_{i-1}$ is almost identical.

Note since $x_{i+k} \not\in I$ we must have $x_{i+k} > t_0 + d_0.$.

We must have $t_0 \geq \frac{1}{2}(x_i + x_{i+k-1})$. For if $t_0 < \frac{1}{2}(x_i + x_{i+k-1}) < x_{i+k-1}$ then $|t_0 - x_i| < |t_0 - x_{i+k-1}|.$ So the point at the $k^{th}$ largest distance from $t_0$ among the $x$'s must be $x_{i+k-1}$. So, $d_0$, which is the mean of the $k^{th}$ and $(k+1)^{th}$ distances among $x$'s from $t_0$ must be
$$
\begin{align}
d_0 &= \frac{1}{2}(|t_0 - x_{i+k-1}| + |t_0-x_{i+k}|)\\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\left( (x_{i+k-1} -t_0) + ( x_{i+k} - t_0) \right)\\ 
    &= \dfrac{x_{i+k-1}+x_{i+k}}{2} - t_0 \\
    &> \dfrac{x_{i+k-1}+x_{i+k}}{2} - \dfrac{x_{i+k-1}+x_i}{2} = \dfrac{x_{i+k}-x_i}{2} = D_2(\frac{x_{i+k}+x_i}{2})
\end{align}
$$
This contradicts the minimality of $d_0$.
So we must have $t_0 \geq \dfrac{x_i+x_{i+k-1}}{2} > x_i$. So the point among $x$'s at the $k^{th}$ largest distance from $t_0$ is $x_i$, and we have
$$
d_0 = \frac{1}{2}(|x_{i+k}-t_0| + |x_i - t_0|) = \frac{1}{2}( (x_{i+k}-t_0) +(t_0 - x_{i} ) = \dfrac{x_{i+k}-x_i}{2} = D_2(\frac{1}{2}(x_{i+k}+x_i)). 
$$
So we have shown $d_0 = D_2( \frac{1}{2} (x_i + x_{i+k} ) )$ for some $i$ and the result follows.